# Error in Oracle 11g: Error(24,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following: ;

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE         PR_CHECKBARCODEFORMAT 
(
  SUBJECT_ID IN VARCHAR2
) 
IS 
BadBarcodeFormat NUMBER(6);
PassOrFail VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO BadBarcodeFormat
  FROM RWILSON.TableA a
  JOIN RWILSON.TableB s
      ON a.SAMPLE_ID = s.SAMPLE_ID
 WHERE s.SUBJECT_ID = Subject_ID
   AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Barcode, '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');

IF BadBarcodeFormat = 0 THEN PassOrFail := 'ALL PASS';
ELSE PassOrFail := 'ALL FAIL';
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(PassOrFail);   

END PR_CHECKBARCODEFORMAT;
```

I had the code working fine when I use sys.TableA and sys.TableB.  I have checked that they exist for Rwilson... So I'm not sure what the problem is...  Any idea?

And I just tried changing it back to sys.  I'm aware, NOW, that you should never create anything in sys.  I was not aware when I first created the tables and procedures.  They are since been replaced, but I'm still having issues...

Please help.

Comment: As an aside, if you must call the procedure's parameters by the same name as the column names you're using in your query, make sure you alias the parameter with the procedure name. E.g. `WHERE s.SUBJECT_ID = PR_CHECKBARCODEFORMAT.Subject_ID` otherwise you'll confuse Oracle and will assume you're comparing the column to itself (which is akin to doing `1=1`, except when the column is null). Or you could make sure your parameters have a different name to the columns and avoid the issue in the first place

Comment: Thanks for the Aside.  I've fixed that.  But do you have any suggestion of why I'm getting that error?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't. You're sure that it's a normal full-stop (aka period) and not some other funky character? Also, does the schema `RWILSON` exist?

Comment: Are TableA and TableB tables or views?

Comment: Rwilson does exist and has the tables within it.  And TableA and TableB are actually tables.

Comment: The error message says it encountered a period at character 12 of line 24. If the code is EXACTLY as you posted, line 24 is the last line, and character 12 is right in the middle of the procedure name. It would be very odd if the compiler can't count lines and characters correctly. Are you sure you don't have an errant period there? Please double-check rather than immediately responding "no, I don't" - you would be shocked how many times people say that, only to come back later and say "sorry, you were right."

Comment: I'm with you mathguy.  I DID have rwilson there, but I took it out and tried to compile the procedure again, but it's STILL giving me that error.  So I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: @Aleksej - how could anything having to do with the tables being tables or views result in that specific error message?

Comment: What tool are you using to compile that? Are you sure you are ONLY selecting those lines to compile? try them in sql*plus

Comment: @mathguy I was trying to exclude the case of a view based on some function with dynamic code. Quite remote, but I believe possible

Comment: Okay... So when I go back to the procedure, it still has rwilson. in it.  But I try to remove it and compile the code and it still comes up with the error?  Why is Oracle derping out?

Comment: I'm not so good with sql*plus...  I have no idea how to do that... -_-

Comment: Alright... So I put the edited code into SQL Plus and ran it... I finally changed the actual code...

Any idea why the IDE derped out and wouldn't fix the code?

Comment: What IDE is that?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer...

Comment: I haven't seen that in SQL Developer before (it is the IDE I use all the time). I have seen something like that recently in Toad - where the IDE would continue to compile a cached query text, even when the editor window showed the edited text. Who knows why - but that is now a SQL Developer question rather than a PL/SQL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR on the comments under the post.

There had been a period but I had tried to edit the code and take it out.  But for some reason, the SQL Developer wouldn't update the code.  So I had to put the code into SQL*Plus and added / at the end.  It recreated the procedure as I have it posted above and everything fine in Developer now...